# How to save the tweets in JSON to txt file in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I would like to save the raw tweets which I get from `Twitter` 
through `Tweepy`.

There's no problem in retrieving the tweets but the problem happens when saving those raw JSON response to a local .txt file.

```
with open("tweets.txt", "a", encoding='utf8') as outfile:  
    for tweet in public_tweets:
        json.dump(tweet, outfile)
```

When I run the above code, it gives me those tweets in Command Prompt but not saving those in file `tweets.txt`.

So, Where is the problem?

**Note :**

- Before marking this question as a duplicate, I would like to say that I saw several StackOverflow posts regarding my question, but none of them solves my problem.
- I use Python Version 3.4.4

Comment: Either your `public_tweets` is empty, or you are opening wrong file.

Comment: You might want to provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .Are you printing the tweets elsewhere? They shouldn't be showing up on stdout if you're writing to a file, for instance.

Comment: Didn't you see that I said I receive those tweets in Command Prompt? & for your second thought, I tried giving new text file with static data along with json.dump, but it saves static data perfectly.

Comment: May be you have a print statement somewhere else which is printing the tweets?

Comment: @pvg I don't understand too, how it is printing when i dump to file.

Comment: 'I don't understand' is not really helpful since nobody can reproduce what you're seeing. For instance, I ran the exact snippet you provided, adding public_tweets = range(10) as a first line. This writes to a text file. What happens when you run such an isolated case?

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun There is no such Print statement in my file. The code which i posted is the only code I have apart from normal tweepy - twitter authentication.

Comment: @pvg Are you using the same Python version which i had mentioned in my question?

Comment: Yes. Did you try the isolated case?

Comment: @pvg Yes. It prints starting from 0 to 9. But what about saving JSON content? That's my question right?

Comment: What do you mean it prints. Does it write to a file?

Comment: Yes. The interger has been written to file.

Comment: Right, so there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted and the problem is elsewhere. That's why you should write an mcve, instead of having someone (me) cajole one out of you.

Comment: Yes, I got the fix. I've added it as a reference for future visitors. You can check my answer if you want to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys. I got the solution. The problem is `public_tweets` is not JSON serializable.

I have to add `._json` to each tweet which i get in for loop.

```
json.dump(tweet._json, outfile, indent=4)
```

Thanks to all!